# Numpy - Replace a number with NaN

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, nan, gdal

I am looking to replace a number with NaN in numpy and am looking for a function like `numpy.nan_to_num`, except in reverse.

The number is likely to change as different arrays are processed because each can have a uniquely define NoDataValue. I have seen people using dictionaries, but the arrays are large and filled with both positive and negative floats. I suspect that it is not efficient to try to load all of these into anything to create keys.

I tried using the following but numpy requires that I use `any()` or `all()`. I realize that I need to iterate element wise, but hope that a built-in function can achieve this.

```py
def replaceNoData(scanBlock, NDV):
    for n, i in enumerate(array):
        if i == NDV:
            scanBlock[n] = numpy.nan
```

NDV is GDAL's no data value and array is a numpy array.

Is a masked array the way to go perhaps?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what is wrong with the solution you provide.  Does it not work properly?

Comment: @Chris Gregg  This solution needs some indenting, does not need to return array (since it is in-place), should probably avoid using `array` as a variable to avoid confusion with np.array, but most importantly, will be terribly slow compared to typical numpy indexing and broadcasting.

Comment: @Paul My concern was the speed, so many thanks for the answer below.  I used the variables simply to make the code clearer, I to would avoid using array as well.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

```
A[A==NDV]=numpy.nan
```

A==NDV will produce a boolean array that can be used as an index for A

Comment: It's a special sequence of bits outside the valid range for the datatype in use.  It's used to signify missing data or the result of a math error that did not produce a valid value.  Hope this helps: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN

Comment: Note that `A.min()` and `A.max()` are not good ways to check if it worked, since they will both return `nan`…  If you wish to get min/max, use `np.nanmin(A)` and `np.nanmax(A)`.

Comment: This doesn't work when A is readonly.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `np.where` to replace a number with NaN.

```py
arr = np.where(arr==NDV, np.nan, arr)
```

For example, the following result can be obtained via

```py
arr = np.array([[1, 1, 2], [2, 0, 1]])
arr = np.where(arr==1, np.nan, arr)
```

[image: res]

This creates a new copy (unlike `A[A==NDV]=np.nan`) but in some cases that could be useful. For example, if the array was initially an int dtype, it will have to converted into a float array anyway (because replacing values with NaN won't work otherwise) and `np.where` can handle that.