# Replace the zeros in a NumPy integer array with nan

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, nan

I wrote a python script below:

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(6).reshape(2, 3)
arr[arr==0]=['nan']
print arr
```

But I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\test.py", line 4, in <module>
    arr[arr==0]=['nan']
ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: 'nan'
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
```

How to replace zeros in a NumPy array with nan?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Numpy - Replace a number with NaN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701714/numpy-replace-a-number-with-nan)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`np.nan` has type `float`: arrays containing it must also have this datatype (or the `complex` or `object` datatype) so you may need to cast `arr` before you try to assign this value.

The error arises because the string value `'nan'` can't be converted to an integer type to match `arr`'s type.

```
>>> arr = arr.astype('float')
>>> arr[arr == 0] = 'nan' # or use np.nan
>>> arr
array([[ nan,   1.,   2.],
       [  3.,   4.,   5.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

An integer array can't hold a NaN value, so a new copy will have to be created anyway; so `numpy.where` may be used here to replace the values that satisfy the condition by NaN:

```py
arr = np.arange(6).reshape(2, 3)
arr = np.where(arr==0, np.nan, arr)

# array([[nan,  1.,  2.],
#        [ 3.,  4.,  5.]])
```