# how to replace a word in a column with NaN in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Supposed I have a column called "quantity";

```
Quantity
1
2
3
Plan
3
2
```

and I want to replace the string `Plan` as NaN, how can I do that in pandas?

thankyou

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace a value in pandas, with NaN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29247712/how-to-replace-a-value-in-pandas-with-nan)

Answer (score 1):

If need replace all non numeric values to NaNs and also if necessary convert values to numeric use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'`:

```
df['Quantity'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Quantity'], errors='coerce')
```

---

If need replace only strings `Plan`:

```
df['Quantity'] = df['Quantity'].replace('Plan', np.nan)
```

Also if need convert to numeric:

```
df['Quantity'] = df['Quantity'].replace('Plan', np.nan).astype(float)
```