# Elements in array change data types from float to string

Tags: python, arrays, append, reshape

When I append elements to a list that have the following format and type:

**data.append([float, float, string])**

Then stack the list using:

**data = np.hstack(data)**

And then finally reshape the array and transpose using:

**data = np.reshape(data,(-1,3)).T**

All the array elements in **data** are changed to strings. I want (and expected) the first and second columns in **data** to be of type float and the third of type string, but instead they are all of type string. [Interestingly, if I do not append the string elements to **data** and adjust the newshape to (-1,2), both columns are floats.] I cannot figure this one out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think as soon as numpy touches it it converts them to a common format unless told otherwise. I don't know if you can tell it dtypes with hstack, but here is an alternative: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26018781/numpy-is-it-possible-to-preserve-the-dtype-of-columns-when-using-column-stack

Comment: Markus, thanks for the help. Your comments guided me to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42813011/replace-an-element-in-a-numpy-array-at-specific-index I was able to find a solution here using dtype=object.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the mix of numbers and strings, np.array will use the common format: string. The solution here is to convert **data** to type *object* which supports mixed element types. This is performed by using:

**data = np.array(data, dtype=object)**

prior to hstack.