# Replace numerical values with NaN in Python

Tags: python, pandas, replace, nan

I want to replace all numerical values in a DataFrame column with NaN

Input

```
A       B       C
test    foo     xyz
hit     bar     10
hit     fish    90
hit     NaN     abc
test    val     20
test    val     90
```

Desired Output:

```
A       B       C
test    foo     xyz
hit     bar     NaN
hit     fish    NaN
hit     NaN     abc
test    val     NaN
test    val     NaN
```

I tried the following:

```
db_old.loc[db_old['Current Value'].istype(float), db_old['Current Value']] = np.nan
```

but returns:

> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'istype'

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701714/numpy-replace-a-number-with-nan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can mask numeric values using `to_numeric`:

```
df['C'] = df['C'].mask(pd.to_numeric(df['C'], errors='coerce').notna())
df
      A     B    C
0  test   foo  xyz
1   hit   bar  NaN
2   hit  fish  NaN
3   hit   NaN  abc
4  test   val  NaN
5  test   val  NaN
```

**`to_numeric` is the most general solution and should work regardless of whether you have a column of strings or mixed objects.**

---

If it is a column of strings and you're only trying to retain strings of letters, `str.isalpha` may suffice:

```
df['C'] = df['C'].where(df['C'].str.isalpha())
df
      A     B    C
0  test   foo  xyz
1   hit   bar  NaN
2   hit  fish  NaN
3   hit   NaN  abc
4  test   val  NaN
5  test   val  NaN
```

Although this specifically keeps strings that do not have digits.

---

If you have a column of mixed objects, here is yet another solution using `str.match` (any str method with a `na` flag, really) with `na=False`:

```
df['C'] = ['xyz', 10, 90, 'abc', 20, 90]
```

```
df['C'] = df['C'].where(df['C'].str.match(r'\D+$', na=False))
df
      A     B    C
0  test   foo  xyz
1   hit   bar  NaN
2   hit  fish  NaN
3   hit   NaN  abc
4  test   val  NaN
5  test   val  NaN
```

Comment: it fails when you use an IP address like `122.168.0.34`

Comment: @MEdwin The first solution won't. Besides, IP addresses are a pretty big leap to make given the question.

Comment: true. The first one is solid.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Works perfectly